# how to split all first elements of tuples in list? (Python)

Tags: python, list, tuples

I made a list called conditionList looking like this:

```
('I'm a man.', 2, 5, 10), ('I'm 20 years old', 6, 8, 10), ('This is just another sentence', 5, 6 10)
```

This `conditionList` is the result of a zip function of 4 lists:

```
conditionlist = zip(sentence, variable1, variable2, variable3)
```

So every element of the list consists of a sentence followed by three numbers.
However, I need a function which would result in the following list:

```
('I', 2, 5, 10), ('am', 2, 5, 10), ('a', 2, 5, 10), ('man.', 2, 5, 10), ('I', 6, 8, 10) etc.
```

In this way, every word is associated with the variables of the sentence they belong to.

How can I go from my conditionList to the desired list?

Thank you.

Comment: how is `I'm` converted to `I am`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presumably what you had is a typo, you just need a comprehension and `str.split`.

```
>>> l
(("I'm a man.", 2, 5, 10),
 ("I'm 20 years old", 6, 8, 10),
 ('This is just another sentence', 5, 6, 10))
>>> [(i, j, k, m) for p, j, k, m in l for i in p.split()]
[("I'm", 2, 5, 10),
 ('a', 2, 5, 10),
 ('man.', 2, 5, 10),
 ("I'm", 6, 8, 10),
 ('20', 6, 8, 10),
 ('years', 6, 8, 10),
 ('old', 6, 8, 10),
 ('This', 5, 6, 10),
 ('is', 5, 6, 10),
 ('just', 5, 6, 10),
 ('another', 5, 6, 10),
 ('sentence', 5, 6, 10)]
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
I'm new to python, could you explain a bit more about how the proposed code works?